# Xamarin wait for task to be complete before continuing

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task

Essentially I'm attempting to load another page however I need something from another method to complete the initialisation, on the initialisation the ViewModel calls off to a server therefore I've awaited it, however, since I need the rest of the application to wait before proceeding, preferably asynchronously.

```
try
{
   Page Page = await Task.Run(() => ReturnPageToLoad(item));
   if (Page != null)
   {
      PageToLoad = Page;
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
      {
          try
          {
              Detail = PageToLoad;
              _nav.SetLoadedPage(PageToLoad);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
              Console.WriteLine($"Error in MainView: {e.Message}");
           }
      });
   }
} catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
}
```

Where I'm defining page just beneath the try, this will return a page to me once everything has been initialised, however, I get null reference objects in multiple places and sometimes the code works completely fine for a few attempts, what leads me to believe it's the threads is if I rush into it, it crashes, if I take it slower it's usually okay.

What I'd like to do is have the rest of the code wait until Page has something returned to it. Is this possible? Thanks!

In the ReturnPageToLoadItem method

```
            try
            {
                if (item.MenuItemType == MenuItemType.Settings)
                {
                    Page Loaded = _nav.ReturnPreLoadedPage(typeof(SettingsView));
                    await (Loaded.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(null);
                    if (_nav.returnLoadedPage() != Loaded.GetType())
                    {
                        return Loaded;
                    }
                }
                else if (item.MenuItemType == MenuItemType.MyTimetable)
                {
                    Page Loaded = _nav.ReturnPreLoadedPage(typeof(TimetableView));
                    await (Loaded.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(null);
                    if (_nav.returnLoadedPage() != Loaded.GetType())
                    {
                        return Loaded;
                    }
                }
                else if (item.MenuItemType == MenuItemType.Support)
                {
                    Page Loaded = _nav.ReturnPreLoadedPage(typeof(ChatView));
                    await (Loaded.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(null);
                    if (_nav.returnLoadedPage() != Loaded.GetType())
                    {
                        return Loaded;
                    }
                }
                else if (item.MenuItemType == MenuItemType.Applications)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else if (item.MenuItemType == MenuItemType.MyProfile)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't exist yet");
                    return null;
                }
                else if (item.MenuItemType == MenuItemType.About)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't exist yet");
                    return null;
                }
                else if (item.MenuItemType == MenuItemType.Home)
                {
                    Page Loaded = _nav.ReturnPreLoadedPage(typeof(HomeView));
                    await (Loaded.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(null);
                    return Loaded;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await Task.Delay(50);
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to load on attempt {retry}: {e.Message}");
                retry--;
            }
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is in `ReturnPageToLoad(item)` and you have not provided that code.

Comment: Sorry! I'll edit my OP to contain the code

Comment: @SushiHangover added the extra bit of code! Thanks for any help!

Comment: _I get null reference objects in multiple places_ What places? _sometimes the code works_ Exactly what errors do you get or what behavior do you see that's wrong. And can you post the full `ReturnPageToLoad` method. Right now it's not clear what behavior you're trying to fix.

Comment: Sorry @JSteward I manage to fix my null reference errors, however now it says to me "Detail must not already have a parent" when it hits Detail = PageToLoad

Answer (score 1):

> on the initialisation the ViewModel calls off to a server therefore I've awaited it, however, since I need the rest of the application to wait before proceeding, preferably asynchronously

I strongly recommend that ViewModels always be initialized synchronously. The only reasonable way to do this is to synchronously load it into a "loading" state (and kick off the call to the server). Later, when you have the data to display, *update* the VM into a "loaded" state. This will give your users a much better experience by showing them a "Loading..." message or spinner rather than making them wait for a remote call to complete.

More info in my [article on async MVVM data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) and [small helper library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async).